# Is "coding on OOP JavaScript" phrased well? I want to use it in a CV

Tags: prepositions, american-english, programming

I need to write in my CV that I write on JavaScript Object Oriented Language. So is the following sentence correct?

> Coding on OOP JavaScript

Comment: Use _in_, not _on_, with that construction. _Coding in Forth is not intuitive_.

Comment: You're welcome. It's the same construction as _writing in Persian, speaking in Esperanto, giving a speech in Navajo, greeting the diplomats in French_, etc. Nothing special.

Comment: Don't be too cryptic. (Spell things out for the person who may be ignorant of the terms you use.)

Comment: It's [debatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107464/is-javascript-object-oriented) whether JS is intrinsically OO. Consider dropping the P to make *OO* qualify JS - "Coding in [object-oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)", or better, "Object-oriented coding in JavaScript".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably in already have a section in your CV/resume called Technical Skills or Programing Languages. So just putting "Object-oriented JavaScript" or "OO JavaScript" as a bullet point is sufficient. Or maybe something like "3 years of OO JavaScript". If you want to specify that for a particular job you used this skill, then you can just say something like "Developed web apps using OO JavaScript". In general, "development" and "programming" are more professional terms to reflect your skill.